# Approval Process Chose Approver Manually and Add comments

Tags: workflow, approval-process

Is there way to add a comment box under the Choose Approver  Manually in Approval process. [image: Choose Approver Manually]

This way for every stage in opportunity can have a separate Request or Note attached to that , and maybe send it through email . Even not email but some how see the attached comments .... Notes and Attachments will show all but this way I want to send it to specific stage

Comment: When you begin doing things in this manner, you begin to lose the benefits of SF automation. It can leave appearance that someone is "manager shopping" to obtain approvals.

Comment: @crmprogdev just need to attach a short description why they are asking for approval if its needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Success Community Idea: Submit for Approval with Comments](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BqAjAAK) is the feature you're looking for. Its currently listed as under point threshold. I suggest you vote this up if you want to see it considered for platform implementation.

**Edit:** As for workarounds, other than adding a text field to Opportunity labeled something like Stage_Approval_Request_Comments, I don't know of one. It can be tracked in history if its a plain text field. If you use a large text area, you can't track it's history and would need a separate field for each stage.

Comment: Thank you very much for your respond  I saw that yesterday. Is there a way around it for now?

Comment: Other than adding a text field to Opportunity labeled something like `Stage_Approval_Request_Comments`, I don't know of one. It can be tracked in history if its a plain text field. If you do a large text area, you can't track it's history and would need a separate field for each stage.